# Getline for vector string

Tags: c++, string, vector, getline

I have a vector string :

```
vector <string> name[20][100];
```

I want to input to `name[0][0]`, but getline is not working. My code :

```
cin.getline(name[0][0], sizeof(name[0][0]))
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `name` is an array of arrays of vectors of strings. Is this what you intended?

Comment: Totally agreeing with Marcelo...  Are you sure you don't just want `char name[20][100];`?

Comment: I've tried char name[20][100] but it still doesn't works, that's why I'm trying other options ._.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are declaring a three-dimensional structure. I suspect you intended only two levels. The next problem is that you are using `std::basic_istream<…>::getline`, which relies on you preparing buffer space in advance (which you are not doing). The free-function form, `std::getline`, is easier and safer:

```
std::string name[20][100];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
        getline(std::cin, name[i][j]);
```

Comment: There is a chance that @user1639776 doesn't understand the difference between `std::string name[20][100]` and `char name[20][100]`. Maybe he needs only 20 strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for(int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
        getline(std::cin,name[i][k]);
    }
}
```

If you want to loop over it.

Comment: yup, I've tried that. but it still doesn't works.. that's why :(

Comment: @user1639776: This could work if you change `vector <string> name[20][100];` to `string name[20][100];`

Comment: @user1639776 what exactly does your array hold that makes it have to be a vector?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another `getline` method.

```
name[0][0].resize(1);
std::getline(std::cin, name[0][0][0]);

std::cout << name[0][0][0];
```

The `getline` method you use takes `char *` not `std::string`.

Also you have array of arrays of vectors of strings.
I think you need just vector of strings.

```
std::vector<std::string> name;
name.resize(20); // will create 20 std::strings (to keep 20 names)

for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); ++i) {
    std::getline(std::cin, name[i]); // fill all of 10 std::strings 
}
```

Comment: @fasked: There's a good chance the OP didn't intend to have three levels of depth in their structure.

Comment: I'm trying to make a loop, so that each names goes : name[0][0], name[0][1], until name[0][100], and it will goes to name[1][0], and so on.

Comment: @user1639776 yes, because you have array of arrays of vectors of strings. I think you need vector of strings only.

Answer (score 0):

Once you do this   `vector<string> name` , you can pretty much also do this `name[0]="a name"`, or this `name.push_back("a name")` , and this       `for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) getline(cin,name[i])`

However, did you mean to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{   
    vector<string> name;
    name.resize(21);

    //name.push_back("a name");
    //name[0]="a name";

     for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
     {
        cout<<"input  name (hit enter twice when done) > ";
        getline(cin,name[i]);

        //cin.clear();
        //cin.ignore( 1000, '\n' );
     }

     for (  i = 0; i < 5; ++i)   cout<<"name "<<i+1
                                     <<" = "<<name[i]
                                     <<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```